# Scope issue with JQuery call in external Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm very new to Javascript and JQuery.

MacOSX 10.8, Safari Version 6.0.3 (8536.28.10)

I have a very simple HTML page with a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wufooTheme8/css/theme.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>
        Course Search
    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://yandex.st/json2/2011-10-19/json2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="application2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="class-find">
        <label>Class Name</label> <input type="text" name="classname" value=""/> 
        <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="classFind(this.form)" />
    </form>     
</body>
```

In my application2.js file I have 2 calls/functions:

```
$('form').bind("keydown", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code  == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});

function classFind(frm) {
  alert('submitted!');
}
```

The first is supposed to stop the enter key from submitting the form to the default action, which I took from another answer on SO but it is not working. The second function just shows an alert when the submit button is pressed, and it is working. I'm sure there's some javascript scope issue or something that I'm not familiar with, but I'm such a noob that I can't figure it out.

Comment: Instead of binding to "keyup", bind to "keydown".

Comment: No, I tried that already. No difference, it's still submitting the form on enter.

Comment: I edited the question to include that info. Tried on Safari 6.0.3 and Firefox 14.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the answer above about making sure your code is in a $(document).ready and changing to keydown.  Since none of those appear to be working. Are you making sure the form has focus before you're pressing enter?  If you just load the page and press enter your keyup/keydown handler won't fire since you are binding the event handler to the form.  Try clicking the input field and then pressing enter and see if the key handler fires.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('form').bind("keydown", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code  == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
      console.log('stop');
    return false;
  }
});
```

});

Here's a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aCL2v/

Comment: Is there a way to bind this to one specific form instead of all the forms on the page?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your code from `keyup` to `keydown` as this executes before.

```
$('form').bind("keydown", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (code  == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: No. That makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping your code in the document ready. It's possible you are trying to bind before the DOM has created the element (i.e. `$('form')` returns an empty jQuery object because no `form` tags yet exist):

```
$(function() {
    $('form').bind("keyup", function(e) {
      var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
      if (code  == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't make a difference, when I hit enter, it's still submitting the form. Do I need to change $('form') to the name of my form?

Comment: Two things, first, can you set a break point in your event handler code and confirm it is actually getting called? Second, you may well need to bind `keydown` rather than `keyup` as Praveen suggested.

Comment: I changed it to keydown already, and edited my question to reflect that. When I add a breakpoint, the function doesn't appear to be called at all.

Comment: Can you try binding `keyup` (or `keydown`) on the document instead of the form?

Comment: No difference in the outcome. Code doesn't get called.